# How can I get batch distance to endpoints?

Tags: here-api

Can I get batch distance from start point to other points (not sequentially) with a single query?

Starting point - Point 1
Starting point - Point 2
Starting point - Point 3

Answer (score 0):

A location service providing customizable route calculations for a variety of vehicle types as well as pedestrian modes also creates a route from a sequence of tracepoints.

Review the following demo link and use your API key to process batch distance with a single query.

Url: https://demo.routing.ext.here.com/